# Find $I_n=\int_{\gamma} e^zz^n \ dz, \ n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle $\{e^{i\theta}:-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi\}$. Using the Cauchy integral formula to find,
>   $$I_n=\int_{\gamma} e^zz^n \ dz, \ n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
>   Hence evaluate the corresponding real integrals.

My attempt:

Consider if $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. If $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then $e^zz^n$ is entire$\implies$ $I_n=0$ by the Cauchy-Goursat theorem.

Now consider if $n\in\mathbb{Z^-}$. If $n\in\mathbb{Z^-}$, then:
\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z^{|n|}} \ dz \\
&=\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{(z-0)^{(|n|-1)+1}} \ dz 
\end{align}
Now, regardless if $n$ is odd or even, $$I_n=\frac{2\pi i}{(|n|-1)!} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(Cauchy Integral formula)}.$$
Hence, $$I_n= \begin{cases} 
      0 & n\in\mathbb{Z^+} \\
      \frac{2\pi i}{(|n|-1)!} & n\in\mathbb{Z^-} \\
   \end{cases}
$$
Is this correct? I am unsure about the $n\in\mathbb{Z^-}$ case.

Comment: Your answer is correct in all cases.

Comment: An easy way to see that $I_n = 0$ for non-negative integers is that the integrand is entire for these n so the integral vanishes by Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Isn't this the Cauchy-Goursat theroem? I don't quite understand what you mean.